# Is there a way for getting a list of all created tests in my emberjs app?

Tags: testing, ember.js, qunit

I need a way to get all my ember tests' nameS, since I want to run them in a separate thread by using the --filter "TEST-NAME" flag.

Right now, I am using a hardcoded array.

Comment: you can use [ember-exam](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-exam) to run in threads (in parallel)

Comment: Good info @GokulKathirvel. This can at least give another option. 
I really wanted to run them individually, and got a boolean output (fail/pass) to explore some flakiness I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not documented, but you can use the `config` object on the root `QUnit` object to get all modules in your test suite, then the tests within each module and their names. Note that any tests *not* in a module will still appear, but with an empty-named module. Here's a [runnable jsfiddle with the example](https://jsfiddle.net/62scnek0/), then the code below.

```
QUnit.test('no-module', (assert) => { assert.equal(0,0) })

QUnit.module('foobar', () => {
  QUnit.test('foo', (assert) => { assert.equal(1, 1) })
  QUnit.test('bar', (assert) => { assert.equal(2, 2) })
})

QUnit.module('batbaz', () => {
  QUnit.test('bat', (assert) => { assert.equal(3, 3) })
  QUnit.test('baz', (assert) => { assert.equal(4, 4) })
})

const testNames = []
QUnit.config.modules.forEach((module) => {
  testNames.push(...module.tests.map(test => test.name))
})

console.log(testNames)
```